# Display tab count in Firefox, without permission to snoop on tabs

Tags: firefox, permissions, firefox-extensions, tabs

Is there a way to display the number of open tabs in Firefox, without giving an extension permission to read your tabs?

Chrome has the open-source [Tab Counter extension](https://github.com/asafh/chrome-tabcounter) you can easily audit.

Firefox has a few "tab counter" extensions, but they require permission to access your tabs ([example](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-count-icon/)).

Answer (score 0):

You can see the maximum number of open tabs in the current session by navigating to `about:telemetry#scalars-tab_search=tab`. This is only updated after restarting Firefox.

To see the current number of tabs in each window, the [Tab Counter Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-counter-plus/) extension is [open source](https://github.com/Loirooriol/tab-counter-plus), seems to be thoughtfully designed, and Firefox doesn't display any permission warning when installing it.